# PhoneGap fileUploadOptions error

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova

I have an issue with PhoneGap with iOS.  I have my app grabbing the photo, and placing it in a div.

but when I go to use the FileUploadOptions() method I get an error:

"ReferenceError: Can’t find Variable: FileUploadOptions"

I'm using PG 0.9.6 with iOS 4.3.3.

It's odd to me that I can access the camera just fine, but the transfer function is not seen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the FileTransfer plugin

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file-transfer
```

Answer (score -2):

`FileUploadOptions` is used by the `FileTransfert` method. Did you take a look a the following Full Example :

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer